# What is the default time period used to attribute a conversion to a channel for different sessions in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Let me clarify my question.

Let's imagine you are using the default attribution model "The Last Non-Direct Click" in your Google Analytics account. You are set a "Top up balance" event tracking and set a "Top up balance" goal. You have a registered user. Today, the user clicked on the URL of your special campaign [www.your-website.com/?utm_source=referral-website&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=winter_campaign](http://www.your-website.com/?utm_source=referral-website&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=winter_campaign) on a referral website and got to your website. The user logged in, but didn't decide to top up the balance and closed the browser. In a few days the user returned to your site simply using a bookmark in the browser, then logged in and toped up the balance.

What is the maximum period of time that may pass to attribute the conversion to the source (the referral website)? For example, 29 days have passed and the conversion is attributed to the source, but if 40 days have passed the conversion is attributed to 'none'. Or are interactions in different sessions not taken into account at all and the logic of the model is applicable only within a session? And where can this be set up, if possible?

The same question is relevant for any other attribution model except "The Last Interaction" if the conversion is not completed immediately after landing on the site, but in another session.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user doesn't delete the cookies (or there is some browser system that deletes it, i.e. ITP), the default timeframe is **6 months**. However, you can update this timeframe within the Google Admin settings.

[image]

**Session and campaign timeout handling**

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795871?hl=en

Comment: Michele, tell me please from what source did you get this information? And what is the Google Admin settings?

Comment: Found: [Session and campaign timeout handling](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795871?hl=en).

Comment: Yes, I just added link and picture in my post :)

Comment: Thanks again! I have to correct you a bit, when using gtag.js campaign data is not stored in cookies, they are sent to Google servers. For this reason, you will not find them in cookies and for this reason you can change the campaign timeout at the resource level.

Comment: Yes, for Universal Analytics too (like gtag). The information of the campaign data in the cookie was only with Classic Analytics, where the session timeout functionality is not available. I explained myself in an unclear way, by deleting the cookies I meant that the Analytics cookie is regenerated and the user becomes a new user (even if he is the same physical person) losing the previous information, therefore also the source. For this reason I made the example of the Intelligent Tracking Prevention of browsers.